# How Can I Get The First Value Before Comma Separated List?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, substr, strpos

Though this question seems similar to ones already asked, but this is a different case.

I have a php hook `<?php echo zublum_display_breadLocation($pid);?>` in my wordpress singular.php that displays 3 different locations, like *country, state, city*

I also have another code I copied online which outputs the first value before comma (,)

```
<?php 
$var = "1,23,45,123,145,200"; 
echo $first_word = substr($var, 0, strpos($var, ','));
?>
```

The problem is when I replace the php hook in my theme with the code I got online, it does not output anything.

This is what I did

```
<?php 
$var = "<?php echo zublum_display_breadLocation($pid);?>"; 
echo $first_word = substr($var, o, strpos($var, ','));
?>
```

Please help, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: `substr($var, o` -> this is the lowercase letter `o`, not a zero (`0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explode would seem the simplest way

```
echo explode(',', $var)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate. Let me try it out.